# Using operators overloading and implicit def for a nice syntax

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to represent boolean queries in a nice way in Scala. I want to be able to define queries this way :

```
"word1" && "word2" || !"word3"
```

which means, as you may guess : *find all the documents containing "word1" and "word2" or not containing "word3"*.

For that purpose, I wrote some case classes, overloaded required operators and created some implicit conversions (I removed the irrelevant class code) :

```
abstract class Query {
    def &&(q : Query) = new And(this,q)
    def ||(q : Query) = new Or (this,q)
    def unary_!       = new Not(this)
}

object Query {
    implicit def toLitteral(s : String) = new Litteral(s)
}

case class Litteral(term : String)     extends Query 
case class And(q1 : Query, q2 : Query) extends Query
case class Or (q1 : Query, q2 : Query) extends Query
case class Not(q  : Query)             extends Query
```

However, when I call my `booleanSearch(q : Query)` method, the conversion does not always go well. For example, `booleanSearch(!"word")` does not compile, saying that `unary_!` is not a member of `String`. Same goes for the `Litteral` conversion which does not always succeed. Is it possible to address that or should I give up on having such a nice expressions ?

Comment: Are you sure the implicit conversion is in scope? This seems to work.

Comment: You are right, I added `import Query.toLitteral` in the other class (of the same package) containing the search method and it worked. But I'm confused, why did `search("myString")` worked without the import ? If it had not worked, I would have tried to import`Query.toLitteral`, but since it worked I thought it was not necessary and taht the compiler could automatically look in the context of `Query` thanks to the `search` signature

Comment: I believe that is the case when there is a direct `String` to `Query` implicit conversion available that would immediately satisfy the function parameter. However the compiler isn't smart enough to look ahead for a conversion that would allow a `unary_!` method for `String` *and then* satisfy the need for a `Query` parameter.

Comment: @LimbSoup ok, thanks, and sorry for such a dumb question